# Creating perfect squares using nested loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I was given this question earlier today :

> You have 100 cats. (You are quite lucky to own so many cats!)
>
> You have arranged all your cats in a line. Initially, none of your
>   cats have any hats. You take 100 rounds walking around the cats. Every
>   time you stop at a cat, you put a hat on it if it doesn't have one,
>   and you take its hat off if it has one on.
>
> The first round, you stop at every cat. The second round, you only
>   stop at every 2nd cat (#2, #4, #6, #8, etc.). The third round, you
>   only stop at every 3rd cat (#3, #6, #9, #12, etc.). You continue this
>   process until the 100th round (i.e. you only visit the 100th cat).
>
> Write a program that prints which cats have hats at the end.

I know that the answer would be all perfect squares. I tried to solve it using JavaScript, my answer is almost correct except for the 100th cat. I think there is something wrong with one of my loops which is why the last element of the array isn't what it should be.

Here is what I came up with :

```
var cats = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  cats.push(0);
}
for (var j = 1; j <= cats.length; j++) {
  for (var k = 0; k <= cats.length; k+= j) {
    if (cats[k] === 0) {
      cats[k] = 1;
    } else if (cats[k] === 1) {
      cats[k] = 0;
    }
  }
}
console.log(cats);
```

The expected output is :

```
[ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
```

Whereas the output I am getting is:

```
[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Comment: @Sidd: it goes from "first" round to "hundreth" round

Comment: The problem appears to be `k <= cats.length` which should be `k<cats.length`

Comment: Also, regardless of what round you are in, you always start at the first cat (`k = 0`)

Comment: If I set k<cats.length, my loop would never touch the hundred cat, wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: The hundredth cat is at index 99. If you loop to 100 you're overshooting by one.

Comment: Change second for loop to `for (var k = j - 1; k < cats.length; k+= j) {`

Comment: @James, setting k = j - 1 makes the changes the the value of cats[0] to 1 when it should actually be 0.

Comment: @SrijithGopal Think about what you'd search Google for with this problem; that's a good indication of what the title should be.

Comment: Right, but cats[0] is the first cat.  So it should be 1.  Just like cats[99] is the hundredth cat, and should also be 1.

Comment: `I know that the answer would be all perfect squares` 2 is not a perfect square, so your expected output is wrong.

Comment: `If I set k<cats.length, my loop would never touch the hundred cat` Javascript arrays are *zero-based*. The first element is `cats[0]` and the 100th element is `cats[99]`. `cats[100]` would be `undefined`

Comment: The core problem is, as Bergi said earlier, that you always start from the first cat but the problem description says that you have to start from the *n*th cat. So on round 2 you visit cats #1, #3, #5 ... instead of #2, #4, #6 ... On round 3 you visit cats #1, #4, #7 ... instead of #3, #6, #9 ... and so on.

Comment: @MattBurland, Updated the expected output.

Comment: @James, I think your suggestion solves it. But could you tell me why it works? I mean wasn't k always going to be equal to j-1 if I start k at 1 and j at 0?

Comment: You're not starting j at zero each time you iterate k!  j varies between 1 and 100, and j - 1 will be the zero-based index of the correct cat to start at

Comment: @James, I updated the expected output, it has all the 1's at perfect squares now.

Comment: So what you're saying it when I use k=j-1, the loop iterates from the correct cat instead of always going through the first cat?

Comment: When j = 1 the iteration goes 0,1,2,...,99.  When j=2: 1,3,5,...,99.  When j=3: 2,5,8...98.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, @James. I got it now and thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you *know* the answers should be all perfect squares up to 100, you could just write your program to do that instead. While writing nested loops can be good for exercise, if you know a problem can be solved in a smaller order O, use it.

```
var n = 100;
var c = Array.apply(null, new Array(n)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
for (var i = 1; 1; i++) {
  var s = i * i;
  if (s > n) break;
  c[--s] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Might as well use `var x = [1,4,9...` then

Comment: @James In the above case, I doubt hard-coding the output would result in shorter code, actually the reverse.

Comment: In ES6, you can use `c = Array(n).fill(0)` (there is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill)).